# IOS development. How do I connect via segue two scenes that are in different storyboards

Tags: ios, storyboard, xib

I have `Main.storyboard` and `CustomTableViewContoller.xib`. Storyboard has instance of `CustomTableViewController.xib` as initial view of NavigationController stack. So, now how can I handle `customtableviewcellclick` as if they were on the same storyboard, but they aren't.

Answer (score 0):

In Xcode 7 you have new Storyboard Reference object in the object library. Drag one onto your storyboard and assign it as the storyboard that you want to, well, reference. You can then create segue to that reference or call it however you like.